# How can I filter a REST query when the field's name is translated?

Tags: rest, odata, localization

I have the following query :

```
/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('Discussions list')/Items?$filter=ContentType eq 'Discussion'"
```

This works perfectly while my profile is set to English.

When I'm set to German though, the query doesn't work, because the "ContentType" field is now called "InhaltStyp".

I need my query to work with 20 languages, and would rather not hardcode the translation in 20 different queries.

The `StaticName` of my field is `ContentType`, is there a way I can filter using this name instead of the `DisplayName`?